# How to upload an image with PHP in SocialEngine

Tags: php, image, upload, socialengine

- How can I write PHP code in order to upload an image using already existing functions in SocialEngine?
- How can I write PHP code in order to get an image which was uploaded using already existing functions in SocialEngine?

Needed Table: engine4_album_photos

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Check `/application/modules/User/controllers/EditController.php` – you will find user's photo editing action (`public function photoAction()`) there. Hope this helps.